# How to change babel output file extensions?

Tags: javascript, npm, babeljs, minify, babel-cli

As the title says, babel `--out-file-extension` doesn't work.

Here is `package.json` :

```
{
  "name": "Assets",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "babel:dev": "babel --presets es2015 Scripts/src -d Scripts/js",
    "babel:min": "babel --presets minify Scripts/src -d Scripts/js --out-file-extension .min.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-minify": "^0.5.1"
  }
}
```

When I run `npm run babel:dev` the result is : `Scripts\src\main.js -> Scripts\js\main.js`

But the same result happens when I run `npm run babel:min`, out files are minified but the extension won't change.

So What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [the docs for `--out-file-extension`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli#set-file-extensions), it states

> Added in: v7.8.0

You are using Babel 6.x, so that option is not available.